# How does Android determine whether to move the layout up when showing the softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-manifest

**How does Android determine whether to move the layout up when showing the softkeyboard?**

Note: I am aware that the activity property `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustResize|adjustUnspecified"`
exists, as described here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft
, but in my case it doesn't seem to have any effect. This is my problem:

I have two activities, pretty much the same layout, but the first one is using a **ListView that holds a list of buttons**. The second activity holds a **scrollview with buttons**.
The rest is the same, same number of buttons, same height of elements, etc.

Now, when I press the search button to open the search input bar, in **my first activity, the entire layouts gets moved up.**
 **While on the second activity, the layout is not being moved up but the softkeyboard just displays on top of it.** This is actually how I want it to behave. How can I achieve the same with my activity that's using the ListView?

In my manifest, initially I didn't specify any `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute, but even if I do, it doesn't make any difference; I tried all three values (adjustPan, adjustResize, adjustUndefined, without any difference).

This is my layout:

1) http://pastebin.com/5zzVxjbK

2) http://pastebin.com/KFtPuHvP

**Interestingly though: when I set my ListView visibility in my layout 1 (left) to View.INVISIBLE, then the layout doesn not get moved up!**

[image]

Comment: @Mathias Lin: I think you have to post some code. just `listview` and `scrollview` does not make anything? My Guess its depends the Layout.

Comment: Here is the code, the 'button section' is named android:id="@+id/category_questions" in both cases;not sure if that's the relevant part. 1) http://pastebin.com/5zzVxjbK, 2) http://pastebin.com/KFtPuHvP

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it has to do with the layout, but how? The Android developer docs doesn't say much in that respect.

Comment: @Mathias - have you tried setting android:isScrollContainer="false" on the ListView? Perhaps that with "adjustPan". I'm not sure that would help, but am curious.

Comment: Also - one difference I noticed was that the ScrollView uses android:layout_height="wrap_content", while the ListView is using "fill_parent". Not sure that would make a difference either.

Comment: @iPaulPro: I just tried setting android:isScrollContainer="false", "adjustPan", android:layout_height="wrap_content" to the ListView/activity, but unfortunately it doesn't make any difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

I can achieve this with a RelativeLayout and setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include android:id="@+id/Header" layout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/Header"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Footer"  />

    <include android:id="@id/Footer" layout="@layout/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You may be able to achive this by setting the footer gravity (or layout_gravity) to "bottom", if you want to keep the LinearLayout, but I am not sure.

Comment: I do have other activities (i.e. containing a listView that fills the screen 90%, with just a small area for a tab header) in my app where the outer layout is a linear layout, and I don't experience the effect there. I only see it in some of the activities. I believe your layout above works, but I would like to understand the logic behind it so I know how I can change the existing LinearLayout and/or what exactly causes this behaviour. I'm sure there are workarounds, but I don't want to fight the symptoms, but rather the origin itself.

Comment: Did you try the footer's gravity (layout_gravity): "bottom" with "adjustPan"?

Comment: It seems that ListViews are "shifted into view" unless they are anchored to the bottom of the screen, and use adjustPan. This default behavior prevents list items from being covered by the soft keyboard.

Comment: I tried to set footer's gravity as mentioned, but no difference. I don't understand why ListViews behave differently than ScrollViews, both are scroll containers, and I have the put into my layout the same way.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I know that a ListView is not "simply" a scroll container. You may have to examine the respective sources to determine the difference. Or just use a RelativeLayout :)